# How to run PhoneGap app on device?

Tags: android, cordova

I tried run a simple app on my usb connected device:

```
phonegap create my-app
cd my-app
phonegap run android -device=0123456789ABCDEF
```

but get error:

```
Unknown platform: -device=0123456789ABCDEF
```

Ant installed and 'path' variable have a path to ant ant ant/bin folders.
Whats can be wrong?

Comment: Have you added the platform using `phonegap platform add android`?

Comment: I have used cordova and if i only have one device I dont specify the device, just `cordova run android` and that runs it fine. If I have no device connected then it will start the emulator, so if you try this without the emulator running and the emulator starts, then I would look at things like BipBip said that the usb driver is not installed or that you have USB debugging selected on your device. Also posting details of your PC and device could be helpful too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the USB driver of your device isn't installed

Answer (score 0):

Try new phonegap app available on play store and use it wirelessly through you computer.

I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

i know it is late, but i'll leave the answer here in case someone finds this.
I was having the same problem, what worked for me was changing the --device for --target, so i run the comand:

```
phonegap run android --target=0430100840 --verbose --stacktrace
```

and everything worked perfectly